# Can not accessing data records using nativeQuery method in springboot and Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I tried `nativeQuery` method for fetching some data without using JPQL in my repository file using `Spring Boot`, `Spring Data JPA` method, I am adding my sample code below:

```
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {
  @Query(value = "select u.username from users u",nativeQuery=true)
  List<Users> findByUsername();
},
```

And calling the method  by,

```
UsersRepository userRepo;
return (List<Users>) userRepo.findByUsername();
```

Then the error I am getting:

> "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). could not execute query; SQL [select u.username from
>   users u]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query".

Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `nativeQuery` which always results in a projection and you try to map that into the `List` of `Users` entity.

This wont work, you have expect a `List<String>` in your case. Or List if you decide to add more columns in the result at some point.

```
@Query(value = "select u.username from users u",nativeQuery=true)
  List<String> findByUsername();
```

Also make sure that the table in the database is actually cassed `users` and the column is `username`. If you are using the entity name and field name then that is another thing to change.